# Tex Installation error, "No pages of output"

Tags: installing

[image]I am a brand new user of Tex. I'm struggling to understand what I am doing wrong. I've downloaded the MacTex package which comes with TexLive. I've updated all the packages according to their recommendations. Upon doing some preliminary research, I suspect that something is wrong with linking to my Ghostscript. I am able to preview Tex Files in TexWorks but I would like to fix TexShop because I prefer it. I've attached a screenshot displaying the error that is being generated.

Thanks so much,
Nakul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing obviously wrong with your TeX  installation. The message just means what it says - your TeX input file doesn't create any output.

You need to add `\maketitle` after the `\title{…}`and `\author{…}` commands, to *typeset* the title.

Please note, if you ask more questions here, don't just show a *picture* of the TeX input, Copy-and-paste the TeX input into the question, so that other people can copy it, *run* the input, and check their answer to the question actually works before they post it.

(Luckily, the answer to this question was simple enough for an experienced TeX user to answer without needing to test it worked!)

Comment: @NakulTiruviluamala If the answer has solved your problem, it would be nice to accept the solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers